# Login with password like Metamask

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, web3py

I would like to create a wallet with a login option using the password just like metamask.

I know how to create a HD wallet, i just dont know how to protect it with a password.

Currently Im using ethersJs and reactnative

Answer (score 0):

[ethereumjs-walet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet) library implements necessary functions to store wallets. [Search it codebase for how to use password protection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet).